# SEO schema-org и JSON+LD для танцевальной студии

Tags: javascript, php, html, seo, schema.org

Имеется сайт танцевальной студии. У стадии есть направления танцев - страницы на сайте, на которых указана вся детальная информация. На каждое направление - отдельная страница, словно страница с товаром в интернет-магазине.

Конечно же сделана основная SEO оптимизация - ключевые слова, описание, заголовок, h1 и т.п. Но полезно внедрить микроразметку (если я правильно понимаю).

1) К какому типу можно отнести танцевальное направление. Это почти как товар, но у товара должна быть однозначно определена цена, а у танцев всё сложнее - тут абонементы на разное количество дней, в разные группы и т.п. Очень не однозначно. Как быть?

2) Правильно ли я понимаю, что можно отказаться от schema-org разметки с помощью HTML и использовать JSON+LD? JSON+LD мне кажется крайне удобным вариантом.

Пример моего кода, но насчёт правильности - много вопросов

```
     <script type='application/ld+json'>
        {
            "@context": "http://schema.org/",
            "@type": "Enumeration",
            "name": "{{$title}}"
            "description": "{{$direction->page_description}}",
            "image": {
                "@type": "ImageObject",
                "caption": "{{$title}}",
                "contentUrl": "{{imgPath($direction->img, 'md')}}",
                "keywords": "{{$direction->page_keywords}}"
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, с json+ld или с другими вариантами.

Answer (score 0):

Из вашего вопроса непонятно, является ли танцевальная студия бизнесом или это бесплатная студия обучения.

Если это коммерческое предприятие, которое за свои выступления получает доход, то в этом случае может быть полезно применять тип верхнего уровня такой как **[DanceGroup](https://schema.org/DanceGroup)** или **[PerformingGroup](https://schema.org/PerformingGroup)** или более общий тип **[LocalBusiness](https://schema.org/LocalBusiness)**. Также можно рассмотреть использование типа **[EntertainmentBusiness](https://schema.org/EntertainmentBusiness)**, но это зависит от конкретных условий бизнеса.

Если же это коммерческие курсы, то в этом случае, возможно, может помогать использование типа **[Course](https://schema.org/Course)** (**[этот тип имеет поддержку Гугл](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/course)**) или более общий тип **[EducationalOrganization](https://schema.org/EducationalOrganization)**.

Также можно рассматривать использование типа **[CreativeWork](https://schema.org/CreativeWork)**, но опять же это зависит от конкретных функций студии.